# Top bound on the value of an algebraic adjunct to elements of a nonnegative irreducible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = ||a_{i j}||_1^n$ be nonnegative irreducible matrix with maximum eigenvalue $r$. Let $A_{i j}(\lambda)$ be an algebraic adjunct for the element $\lambda \delta_{i j} - a_{i j}$ in determinant $A(\lambda) = |\lambda E - A|$. It is known that $A_{i j}(\lambda) > 0$ when $\lambda \geqslant r$. Is it possible to write a top bound estimate to this value? For instance, probably $A_{i j}(\lambda) \leqslant a_{i *}$, where $a_{i *}$ denotes the sum of elements in the row $i$ of matrix $A$, or at least $A_{i j}(r) \leqslant a_{i *}$ or something like this.

**EDIT:**
In a book they say that for stohastic matrix $P$ it's easy to verify that $P_{i i}(1) \leqslant 1$. I don't understand why this is to be true.

There is a property that eigenvector $\vec{x}$ corresponding to eigenvalue $r$ may be written using algebraic adjuncts as $\vec{x} = (A_{i 1}(r), A_{i 2}(r), \dots, A_{i n}(r))$, for any $i$, $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$. I have tried to use it but with no luck as well.

Comment: I've edited the post a little to show the direction I was trying to think. Maybe it's not as easy to show for an arbitrary algebraic adjunct, but it should definetly be some trivial reasoning for diagonal algebraic adjuncts of stohastic matrix, because it's written in a book...

Comment: I think that in general $A_{i j}(\lambda)$ can't be bounded, because it is a determinant of a nonnegative irreducible matrix, that tends to infinity as $\lambda \to \infty$. But I think we may put something like $A_{i j}(\lambda) \leqslant A_{i j}(r) (\lambda - r)^M$ that will be sufficient.

Comment: If I remember right, any SUBMULTIPLICATIVE matrix norm is at least as big as the spectral radius.

Comment: The maximum-norm has to be multiplicated with n (in general $\sqrt{mn}$, if A is not a square matrix) to be submultiplicative.

Comment: This is true for the determinant $|P_{2 2}|$ of matrix $P_{2 2}$, but we need the statement for algebraic adjunct $|P_{2 2}(1)|$ which is a determinant for matrix $(E - P_{2 2})$ and we can't yet say that all eigenvalues of $(E - P_{2 2})$ doesn't exceed 1. We can say that eigenvalues of $(E - P_{2 2})$ doesn't exceed absolute row-sums, but this isn't enough to get $|P_{2 2}(1)| \leqslant 1$, because absolute row-sums aren't bounded with 1.

Comment: OK, lets continue tomorrow ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention. I appreciate your help and actually this discussion gave me some ideas, because I guess with this method it's possible to get estimates like $A_{i j}(r) \leqslant M^n$, but yet it's not enough for what I need because it depends on the size of the matrix. Also it must be trivial... But once again, thank you very much!

Comment: I will now delete most of my posts. I guess you can do the same.